# homotopy domination that splits a non-split epimorphism and still wants to be a homotopy equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, algebraic-k-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, homotopy-theory

Can a homotopy domination by a space supporting a free action of $G$ be promoted to a homotopy equivalence with such a space? As stated, this is not a serious question (multiply by an $EG$). But with a bit of additional data it seems to make more sense:

> Fix a non-split epimorphism $f:\bar G\to G$ (I'm thinking of $f:\Bbb Z/p^2\to\Bbb Z/p$ to begin with, though eventually I would need something wilder). Suppose that $\bar G$ acts freely on $X$ and $G$ acts freely on $Y$ (spaces or CW-complexes).
>   If there exist a $\bar G$-map $u:X\to Y$ and a (nonequivariant) map $d:Y\to X$ such that $X\xrightarrow{u}Y\xrightarrow{d} X$ is homotopic to the identity, then do there exist $Y'$, $u'$ and $d'$ with similar properties, such that additionally 
>   $Y'\xrightarrow{d'}X\xrightarrow{u'} Y'$ is homotopic to the identity?

The question is, has anybody ever studied this type of problem? If not, what techniques could possibly apply? If you do [the Mather trick](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sferry/ps/finite.pdf), the question is about extending the action of $G$ on $Y$ over the mapping torus of a non-equivariant self-map (though if it doesn't extend for one particular self-map, that need not be the end of the story). Also I don't see how the finiteness obstruction could help here. Could it have anything to do with $Nil$ groups, say?

Comment: The problem might become simpler if one insists additionally that $Y'$ be equivariantly homotopy dominated by $Y$. (I do actually care about a rather weak form of this condition, which is likely to come for free in my context.) With this addendum, even the simplified version of the problem becomes meaningful: Given a space $X$, homotopy dominated by a space $Y$ with a free action of $G$, does $Y$ equivariantly homotopy dominate a space $Y'$ with a free action of $G$ such that $Y'$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$?